# Decoding attachments url from php website

Tags: php, ios, webview, download

So I have a website that is built in php (IP Board), I have a download manager in my ios app that can detect file extensions like zip, deb etc. However I can't find a way to have it recognize the url that board uses to attach files.

My code I use now:

```
//Download manager
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *theRessourcesURL = [request URL];
        NSString *fileExtension = [theRessourcesURL pathExtension];

        NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", fileExtension);
        if ([fileExtension hasSuffix:@"zip"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"deb"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"rar"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp3"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"pdf"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"exe"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"mp4"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"flv"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"torrent"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [fileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"]) {

            NSError *error = nil; //error setting
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
            NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];

            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

            HCDownloadViewController *dlvc = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
            [dlvc downloadURL:theRessourcesURL userInfo:nil];


            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dlvc animated:YES];

            dlvc.delegate = self;
            return NO;
        }
        else {
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Currently the site uploads attachments which gives a link like this:

http://mysite.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=38354

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE 7/17:

From what I have tried to gather, I'm trying to use something like what follows below. But I can't seem to link it up to the download manager to start the download view controller.

```
//New method I'm trying
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *userId= [prefs stringForKey:@"userIdkey"];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=%@",userId];

//Need to push this view controller like the file extension code above
    HCDownloadViewController *dlvc = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
    [dlvc downloadURL:theRessourcesURL userInfo:nil];
```

UPDATE 7/18:

Trying something else here, still not pushing the view controller though.

```
NSURL *url = [request URL];
NSString *id = @"12212323";
NSString *fullURL = [[url pathExtension] initWithFormat:@"www.mysite.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=%@", id];
```

Throws this log:

> *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  *** initialization method
>   -initWithFormat:locale:arguments: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSPathStore2: Create a concrete instance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adjusting some things on the server side and then found the extension by using this.

```
NSString *fileExtension = [[externalURL absoluteString] pathExtension];
```

Don't know why this was marked as edited, when the code was exactly the same..

```
  //My code
    NSString *fileExtension = [[externalURL absoluteString] pathExtension];
```